# A questionnarie question

Tags: sentence-usage

Let's assume that this is the first time you want to visit a doctor. Most of the doctors usually have a prepared questionnaire which is submitted to you to be filled in by you at the first meeting and it will be expanded as time passes and during your treatment process which would form your personal documents.
I wonder which question do you normally expect to come across while you read the queries?

> 1. Who **recommended** us/me to you?
> 2. Who **referred** us/me to you?
> 3. Who **introduced** us/me to you?
> 4. Who **presented** us/me to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of your suggestions, (2) is the best, but you need to swap the direct and indirect objects (the patient is the one who is referred to the doctor):

> Who **referred** you to us?

(1) also works, but sounds less idiomatic to me:

> Who **recommended** us to you?

But more common and idiomatic is:

> How did you hear (or learn) about us?

Also note that in the U.S. (and apparently also the U.K.) health care system, **a referral** is a specific term when one doctor tells you to go see another doctor (often a specialist in a particular field). This is different than the word-of-mouth referral in (2).

Comment: Thank you @TypelA. But which one is correct? "Who referred **you to us**" or "Who referred **us to you**"? Meanwhile, why #3 doesn't sound idiomatic to you?

Comment: @A-friend It is "who referred **you** to **us**". The other way around would mean someone told the doctor about you and suggested they take you on as a patient. As for (3), it is wrong because **to introduce** suggests someone accompanied you to the doctor's office and said "A-friend, meet Dr. X. Dr. X, this is A-friend." An introduction is when a third party puts two people in mutual contact with each other.

Comment: In the UK a doctors referral means: a general practitioner, knew this required somebody specialised and referred their patient to the specialist.

Answer (score 2):

From a Brit the only one option is valid:

> Who recommended us/me to you?

---

**Refer**
if you had been referred they would have a a referral letter in front of them, explaining why their services were required, this letter would be from another medical professional.

As from the oxford dictionary:

> **2.1** (refer someone to) Send or direct someone to a medical specialist.
>    ‘she was referred to a clinical psychologist for counselling’

---

**Introduce**, you always know who has introduced you, once again in the old days a letter of introduction was sent, but these days the person is standing in front of you.

> 2. Make (someone) known by name to another in person, especially formally.
>
> ‘I must introduce you to my wife’

---

**Present**
Once again the person presenting you to someone else is with you in the room.

> VERB
>   [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 2 Formally introduce (someone) to someone else.
>   ‘may I present my wife?’